# Не всегда выполняется AsyncTask при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

При запуске моего приложения должен отработать такой код:

```
class AddListNameGroup extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pkgh.edu.ru/obuchenie/shedule-of-classes.html").timeout(10 * 1100).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            android.util.Log.e("Не подключено", String.valueOf(e));
        }

        if (doc != null) {
            Elements allShedule = doc.select("div.column.one-fourth");
            for (Element link : allShedule) {
                System.out.println(link.select("h4.expanded").text());
                nameGroup.add(link.select("h4.expanded").text());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

В классе этот подкласс объявлен как поле 
`AddLsitNameGroup addlistnamegroup;`
В методе `OnCreate` я его инициализирую

```
addlistnamegroup = new AddListNameGroup();
addlistnamegroup.execute();
```

Но он не всегда выполняется. Экземпляр подкласса является полем класса. В OnCreate я запускаю я запускаю этот поток. 
В логах такое:

```
01-11 16:56:46.590 10363-10363/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-11 16:56:46.620 10363-10373/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
01-11 16:56:46.725 10363-10363/? I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package common
01-11 16:56:46.725 10363-10363/? I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package com.bulletproof136.material.ColorsDark
01-11 16:56:46.725 10363-10363/? I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package com.bulletproof136.material.ColorsDark
01-11 16:56:46.795 10363-10363/? W/ResourceType: For resource 0x01030224, entry index(548) is beyond type entryCount(15)
01-11 16:56:46.795 10363-10363/? W/ResourceType: For resource 0x01030224, entry index(548) is beyond type entryCount(15)
01-11 16:56:46.795 10363-10363/? W/ResourceType: For resource 0x01030128, entry index(296) is beyond type entryCount(15)
01-11 16:56:46.795 10363-10363/? W/ResourceType: For resource 0x01030237, entry index(567) is beyond type entryCount(15)
01-11 16:56:46.795 10363-10363/? W/ResourceType: For resource 0x01030237, entry index(567) is beyond type entryCount(15)
01-11 16:56:47.295 10363-10385/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-11 16:56:47.310 10363-10363/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
01-11 16:56:47.450 10363-10385/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-11 16:56:47.460 10363-10385/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-11 16:56:47.505 10363-10385/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-11 16:56:47.560 10363-10385/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-11 16:56:47.560 10363-10385/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-11 16:56:48.060 10363-10363/com.example.admin.parserasp W/ResourceType: For resource 0x01030237, entry index(567) is beyond type entryCount(15)
01-11 16:56:48.060 10363-10363/com.example.admin.parserasp W/ResourceType: For resource 0x01030237, entry index(567) is beyond type entryCount(15)
01-11 16:56:48.185 10363-10363/com.example.admin.parserasp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@230484b8 time:92405039
```

Comment: В логах нет полезной информации. Полезно было бы увидеть где и как вы задачу стартуете.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб `addlistnamegroup.execute()` в методе `onCreate`

Comment: И если вы добавите вывод в лог чего-нить из конструктора таска и его методов (в самом начале тела метода) то в логах будет так таки пусто?

Comment: если вы стартуете один и тот же объект `AsyncTask`, то не надо так

Comment: Таки да. Приведите в вопросе инициализацию таска и вызов его `execute`. Может он у вас статический или вы его несколько раз запустить пытаетесь не переинициализировав.

Comment: Да нет же, я хоть и новичок , но не настолько :D 
Но хорошо, в вопросе укажу как у меня.

Comment: Нет ли других тасков, выполняющихся в приложении в тот же момент? В других активити, фрагментах, сервисах?

Comment: Сервисов фрагментов в приложении нет, активити запускается только одно и это именно то, на которое я жалуюсь

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `execute()` попробуйте `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)`

Comment: Не помогло, если честно

Comment: @UliyanRomanov это помогает в том случае если по каким то причинам перед этой асинкТаской запустилась другая, а в начиная с Андроида 3.0 асинкТаски выполняются только последовательно. Значит у вас проблема в чем-то другом. Попробуйте добавить лог непосредственно перед `addlistnamegroup.execute();` и в самой первой строке `doInBackground ` и посмотреть отрабатывают ли они.